# WebDAV on CentOS - getting 403 error when attempt to upload

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, webdav

I configured Apache2 to allow WebDav on a directory (CentOS 5 / Plesk 8.6):

- WebDav is enabled in httpd.conf
- /var/lib/dav/lockdb is writeable by Apache
- My target dir is chmod 777
- My target dir is chowned apache:psacln
- using Basic Authentication (setup by Plesk interface)

in my vhost.conf I have:

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/target_dir>
        Dav On
    AllowOverride none
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I can connect to the directory using authentication fine and download files from it. But I cannot write to the dir. I get a 403 Error when I attempt to upload or create a dir.

Anyone have any tips?

Thanks in advance -

**Update - 6/5** Using the comments below I've isolated the issue to being some type of conflict with .htpasswd protected directories. I can created an unprotected dir and enable WebDAV uploads fine. But once I enable Basic Auth on the directory everything goes south. I can read but no longer upload.

This is my vhost.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/>
        AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
        AuthName "Login"
        AuthType Basic
        Require valid-user

        DAV on
    AllowOverride none
        <Limit PUT POST DELETE PROPFIND PROPPATCH MKCOL COPY MOVE LOCK UNLOCK>
                Require valid-user
        </Limit>
</Directory>
```

**Update 6/6**

Was able to get WebDAV working on a different domain with minimal effort. The only difference between the two domains is that in the one which refuses to allow write access I have a DocumentRoot directive:

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/webroot
```

Might this be causing some problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently struggled with the same problem on my Fedora 10 system.  In my case the culprit was some odd redirection that I was doing in Apache.  Specifically, I use a content management system (Drupal, to be exact) that within it's .htaccess includes the following redirection logic to redirect missing files to a PHP script:

```
# Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It makes sense that the above only affects the PUT method since in that case REQUEST_FILENAME does not exist.

Not having the WebDAV area inside of the Drupal area, which seems like a reasonable constraint, fixes the problem.

Also, I think it is likely that SELinux would result in a different error, but it's not mentioned in the discussion above.  Did you try disabling SELinux?

Comment: This pretty much nailed the problem. I switched on WebDAV on a subdomain without mod_rewrite and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 7):

Same problem. Solved by:

```
<Location /xyz>
    DAV On
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "webdav-xmarks"
    AuthDigestProvider file
    AuthUserFile "/home/xy/xba/digest-password"
    Require valid-user
    RewriteEngine off <-- this part solved it!
</Location>
```

Comment: Great suggestion about disabling `mod_rewrite` within the WebDAV `<Location>` via `RewriteEngine Off` – this helped solve a problem with our WebDAV installation on RHEL 6 and is a much cleaner solution than trying to write `mod_rewrite` rules to ignore WebDAV requests which on our server at least were not proving to be completely reliable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Same problem.

Solved by creating a .htaccess file in the webdav directory with :

```
RewriteEngine off
```

Found here: http://annoyingtechnicaldetails.wordpress.com/2007/07/20/webdav-vs-drupal-htaccess-redirect-rules/

Answer (score 1):

What does your error_log say?  That's the first place to look.

Also, look in the regular access_log; sometimes some DAV clients will try to do DAV things at higher level directories than where you're doing your work, which requires them to have at least read-only DAV access up to the virtualhost root.

Comment: I don't see anything in error_log specific to web_dav.

Comment: okay now we're getting somewhere:

<b>error_log</b>
[Thu Jun 04 21:27:14 2009] [error] [client xxx] Unable to PUT new contents for /depot/flvplayer.swf.  [403, #0]
[Thu Jun 04 21:27:14 2009] [error] [client xxx] (2)No such file or directory: An error occurred while opening a resource.  [500, #0]

<b>access_log</b>
2xx.xxx.xxx.xxx - user [04/Jun/2009:21:46:38 -0400] "PUT /depot/flvplayer.swf HTTP/1.1" 403 423 "-" "WebDAVFS/1.2.7 (01278000) Transmit/3.6.7 neon/0.25.4"

Comment: So.. not clear why I'm getting a 403. I can read files from the dir and also delete them (!), but I cannot PUT them.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using limit: (for example)

```
  <Limit PUT POST DELETE PROPFIND PROPPATCH MKCOL COPY MOVE LOCK UNLOCK>
    Require valid-user
  </Limit>
```

Comment: Okay - added this to my Directory in vhost.conf - still not working, getting 403 error

Answer (score 0):

As Ram Prasad said, you need that Limit statement in the Directory entry in your vhosts.config file.

You also need a .DAV directory that is owned by apache in the same directory as your .htaccess file. I have found this usually causes the 403 error, as Apache uses this folder to write temporary files to.

See also: http://www.webdav.org/mod_dav/install.html

Comment: I added a .DAV dir to the top level (httpdocs) where .htaccess is and chowned to apache:apache. Still getting 403 error.

Comment: BTW - not using .htaccess to set directives, using vhost.conf (plesk)

Comment: The .DAV dir should be in the directory that you have configured to be shared by WebDAV, not in the top level httpdocs dir.

Comment: Tried it. I created a .DAV folder in my WebDAV folder, chowned to apache:apache and even chmod to 0777 still no luck. Tried creating a .dav folder as well just in case its a case issue.

Comment: Meant to say still getting the 403 - its rather baffling!

Comment: Okay - i've narrowed it down to some sort of permissioning issue or conflict. I created a non-protected directory on a subdomain (open to everyone) and am able to upload just peachy.